# defining custom mapping in searchkick does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a Campaign model and this is how my custom mapping looks like:

```
searchkick mappings: { 
 campaign: {
   properties: {
     title: {type: "string", analyzer: "snowball"},
     deal_title: {type: "string", analyzer: "snowball"},
     description: {type: "string", analyzer: "snowball"}
   }                                         
 }                                           
}
```

when I reindex campaign documents, and do

```
c = Campaign.search "this is"
```

I get the following error:

```
Searchkick::InvalidQueryError: [400] {  
   "error":{  
      "root_cause":[  
         {  
            "type":"query_parsing_exception",
            "reason":"[match] analyzer [searchkick_search] not found",
            "index":"campaigns_development_20160205130806185",
            "line":1,
            "col":96
         }
      ],
      "type":"search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason":"all shards failed",
      "phase":"query",
      "grouped":true,
      "failed_shards":[  
         {  
            "shard":0,
            "index":"campaigns_development_20160205130806185",
            "node":"kiTXKzIEQjuI9UNDzXZ1DA",
            "reason":{  
               "type":"query_parsing_exception",
               "reason":"[match] analyzer [searchkick_search] not found",
               "index":"campaigns_development_20160205130806185",
               "line":1,
               "col":96
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status":400
}
```

Also when I add merge_mappings: true to the existing mapping,

```
searchkick merge_mappings: true, mappings: { 
 campaign: {
   properties: {
     title: {type: "string", analyzer: "snowball"},
     deal_title: {type: "string", analyzer: "snowball"},
     description: {type: "string", analyzer: "snowball"}
   }                                         
 }                                           
}
```

and

```
search c = Campaign.search "this is"
```

, I get results with campaigns having words "this is" in either of title/deal_title/description.

But since I am using snowball analyzer, these common stop words should have never been indexed and thus return 0 result.

Also in the second scenario with mapping changed, it gives no error. So I think that searchkick does not identify snowball analyzer and since I did merge_mappings: true, it must have used default analyzer for indexing. And thats why it does not give any error.

So the question really is: Is there something wrong in first mapping that I showed or does searchkick does not identify snowball(or any analyzer for that matter, tried the same thing with stop analyzer) analyzer?

Comment: have you get any solution for that?